# Do you keep scorestreak if you change loadout when both class have requisition

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

Call of duty, world war 2. If you start playing as one class with requisition active and change to another class which has requisition after 1 to X kills, does your scorestreak reset?

Playing online now in tournament and no time to test. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not reset. You keep the streak.

Comment: Is there by any chance an official statement or a video showing this or can you make one? It's not necessary, but it would improve the answer, because currently people would just have to take your word for it.

Comment: @Fabian I agree but unfortunately don't have a video (I had the same question last week and just went ahead and answered it through first-hand experimentation).